# Elementary question on measure a Lebesgue integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to work through problems and am very new to measure theory. I have a feeling that this problem is simple, but have no idea about how to get started. I am hoping to get some direction, but not the answer. Thank you.

Let $f: X \to [0, \infty]$ be measurable and $\int_{X} f d\mu < \infty$. Show that  $\mu(\left\{x : f(x) =\infty\right\})=0.$

Comment: **Hint**: Assume $\mu(\left\{x : f(x) =\infty\right\})=\varepsilon >0$.  What would be the the value of $\int_{X} f d\mu$?  Try to apply the definition of $\int_{X} f d\mu$.

Comment: Different hint: Let $M= \{x \mid f(x) = \infty\}$. Note that $n \cdot 1_M \leq f$ for all $n \in \Bbb{N}$.

Comment: I think I have it, but just to check I will show what I did.  Using the hint provided by @PhoemueX we can define $M_n =\left\{x: f(x) >n\right\}$, and define $\chi_{A_n}$ as the characteristic function for $A_n$. We can then show that $\mu(A_n) \leq \frac{1}{n} \int f d\mu$. From here the proof is pretty simple.

Comment: @Krampus: That is not what I intended, but it shows the claim, since $M \subset M_n$ for all $n$. (You are somehow inconsistent with the use of $M_n$ and $A_n$).

Comment: @PhoemueX Sorry, I am working on another problem at the same time that uses $A_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E=\{x: f(x) = \infty\}$ and $E_n=\{x : f(x) > n\}$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. Then $\mu(E_1)<\infty$ (as otherwise $\int f\ \mathsf d\mu =\infty$), and $E_n\supset E_{n+1}$, so by continuity from above,

$$\mu(E) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(E_n). $$
For each $n$, we have $$\int f\ \mathsf d\mu \geqslant \int_{E_n} f\ \mathsf d\mu > n\mu(E_n), $$
so that $\mu(E_n)<\frac1n\int f \ \mathsf d\mu$. Since $\int f \ \mathsf d\mu<\infty$, it follows that 
$$\mu(E) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mu(E_n) < \frac1n\int f \ \mathsf d\mu, $$
and hence $\mu(E)=0$.